# How to hide view (directive ng-view) in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, session, scope, coldfusion

I have an Angularjs application. In the main page I call the view with **ng-view** directive. I would like to hide the view in according to the value of a JS variable.

Indeed I retrieve the value of a Coldfusion SESSION variable ( that I transform in a JS variable with this instruction:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <cfoutput>
        var #toScript(SESSION.viewerRole, "viewerRole")#;
    </cfoutput>
</script>
```

And I pass this variable in each controller.

I try to display the view if the value of *viewRole* is equal to 1 and I try to display an error message if it's not the case:

**In my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">


        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            <cfoutput>
                var #toScript(SESSION.viewerRole, "viewerRole")#;
            </cfoutput>
            console.log("viewerRole: " + viewerRole); //OK it's working
        </script>           

        <title>My App/title>    
    </head>

    <body ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app">

        ....................................................

        <cfif #SESSION.viewerRole# eq 1>            
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        <cfelse>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <div>
                  you do not have sufficient access rights to access to this section
                </div>              
            </div>      
        </cfif>

        <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/appService.js"></script>

        <script src="lib/js/ngDialog.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Here my app.js:**

```
var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngDialog', 'angular-popover']);

// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
       return {
            // On request success
            request : function(config) {
                // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            // On request failure
            requestError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.  
                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            // On response success
            response : function(response) {
                //console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.
                // Return the response or promise.
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // On response failure
            responseError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.
                //Check whether the intercept param is set in the config array. 
                //If the intercept param is missing or set to true, we display a modal containing the error
                if (typeof rejection.config.intercept === 'undefined' || rejection.config.intercept)
                {
                    //emitting an event to draw a modal using angular bootstrap
                    $rootScope.$emit('errorModal', rejection.data);
                }

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
 }]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, ngDialogProvider){

    console.log("CONFIG - adminRole: " + adminRole + " -- authorRole: " + authorRole + " -- viewerRole: " + viewerRole ); // It's correctly retrieved

    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }

    // disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider to intercept http calls
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');

    $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
      controller: 'ctrlContacts',       
    })
    .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
      controller: 'ctrlViewContacts'
    })  
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
});    

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});

app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, $timeout, MyTextSearch, ContactService, RequestService, ngDialog){
    $scope.adminRole =  adminRole;
    $scope.authorRole = authorRole;
    $scope.viewerRole = viewerRole;

    console.log("ctrlContacts: " + adminRole + " -- authorRole: " + authorRole + " -- viewerRole: " + viewerRole ); // It's correctly retrieved

    // LOAD THE LAST REQUESTS
    RequestService.loadLastRequests().success(function(lastRequests, status, header, config){
        .................................
    }   
});
```

All is working but if I refresh the page with F5 I have a problem: the view is not displayed and the error message is displayed (you do not have sufficient access rights to access to this section).

Could you help me please with that?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is your index page a `.html` page or a `.cfm` page? It will only execute the ColdFusion code if it is a `.cfm` page. What is the value of your session variable in the console log when you refresh?

Comment: The main page is index.cfm. The other views are .html The value in the colsole is correct and is -1

Comment: If the value in the console is correct and is equal to `-1` then the code is working correctly. Or at least correctly for how you have it written. `<cfif #SESSION.viewerRole# eq 1>            
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        <cfelse>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <div>
                  you do not have sufficient access rights to access to this section
                </div>              
            </div>      
        </cfif>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the problem. I put in session data in ***application.cfc*** in the function ***onrequeststart***. But I didn't take in account the current values in session if they existed.

Now it's solved